# Alternative to table variable in TVF

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a TVF and make use of table variables inside of it.
One of the last steps is to delete several (thousands) lines of it.
Exactly this query increases the runtime dramatically.
Changing the code using temp tables reduces runtime again, but unfortunately temp tables must not be used in TVF. 
I can't change the TVF to a SPROC.

Any ideas how to enhance performance?

I added only the part of the TVF which slows it all down. Prior to this, timestamps are collected and preprocessed in `@Result`. `@C` collects includes the ids which have to be modified at this time.

```
UPDATE R
SET starttime = CASE R."myFunction"
                    WHEN 1 THEN Date1
                    WHEN 0 THEN Date2
                END
FROM @Result AS R
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM @c AS c
    WHERE c."id" = R."id")
```

If the above code is executed without the update it executes nearly instantly, so I think the right-sided function isn't the bottleneck. Even if I change `SET starttime...` to a fixed value, runtime stays nearly the same.
`@Result` holds about 250.000 lines, `@c` about 20.000.
I already added indices to the table vars - without big success.

Comment: I suggest you to try to create a new @table_variable with only new `starttime` and `id` and `JOIN` it later with the @Result table to produce final result. The point is to replace UPDATE to INSERT and later JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your query to use a join instead of using `WHERE EXISTS` (which is known to perform worse in some cases):

```
UPDATE R
    . . .
FROM @Result AS R
INNER JOIN @c AS c ON c."id" = R."id"
```

Comment: INNER JOIN instead of WHERE EXISTS does not make any crucial difference.

Comment: @Nico you check this, or is it just an assumption that it has no difference?

Comment: @Vasily I checked this.